# Execute function from the shell directory in cron file present in model dir of a module

Tags: magento-1.9, model, shell

I have created a custom code in shell directory in magento 1.9.2.3 and executed this file from the ssh using php filename.php from the shell dir. now i want this code to be executed in the cron file present in the model of a module.

How can i run a function from shell dir in cron file present in the model folder.

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to move the main logic of your shell script to a custom module and then call this custom module/method from the shell script.
In the same way, you will be able to call the method from the Magento Cron as well.